# Google Docs Spreadsheet: Counting Form Results

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I have a form that fills in a Google Spreadsheet. One of the columns is a gender drop down with "Male" or "Female" options.

How do I get a total of the # of Males? Is there a =Sum() function that I can say Male =1 and Female =0 or something like that?

Comment: This does not sound like a programming question. Perhaps http://webapps.stackexchange.com?

Comment: moderator please move question to webapps

Comment: This question is probably better fitter at webapps indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's a formula for that. It called `COUNTIF` e.g.

```
=COUNTIF(B:B; "Male")
```